# Get all nodes under YAML path

Tags: java, yaml, bukkit

I have a YAML file that looks like this:

```
Main:
  topofhouse:
    x: 276.4375
    y: 71.0
    z: -60.5
    yaw: -290.7768
    pitch: 35.400017
  2ndfloor:
    x: 276.5
    y: 67.0
    z: -60.5
    yaw: -8.626648
    pitch: 16.199997
  home:
    x: 276.5
    y: 63.0
    z: -60.5
    yaw: -18.976715
    pitch: -32.850002
```

Is there a way to get all nodes under `Main`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the node IDs contained in `Main`:

```
file.getConfigurationSection("Main").getKeys(false);
```

Output:

```
Set["topofhouse", "2ndfloor", "home"]
```

The [`ConfigurationSection.getConfigurationSection(String path)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getConfigurationSection(java.lang.String)) method is used to get the path on which to operate.

The [`ConfigurationSection.getKeys(boolean deep)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getKeys(boolean)) method will get you all node IDs within the current path as a `Set<String>`.
When `deep` is set to `true`, it will get all the nodes in the children and subchildren too, however, all relations between them will be lost.